# Child Div Percentage of Parent Div

Tags: css

I am trying tocreate a fixed position nav bar that is 25% of its container div, but for some reason, the nav bar is being sized at 25% of the viewport and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've replicated the issue in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6yJG/1/

EDIT: Although changing the positioning of the NAV div from fixed to absolute fixes the size problem, it causes the navigation not to be able to scroll with the page. So is there a work around that would allow me to fix position the nav and still have it be 25% of its parent container?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Coffee Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section class="main">
                Test
            </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(210,159,182);
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

nav {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

nav ul li {
    line-height: 50px;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-family: 'Grand Hotel', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 31px;
    color: rgb(104,58,122);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; /* reinforce default space */
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(104,58,122);
}

.main {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.fix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: it's because `position:fixed` it will calculate width relative to viewport

Comment: If I remove the fixed positioning, the nav won't scroll with the page. But even when I changed it to relative, the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* due to `position: fixed;`, which gives it a size of 148px. Changing it to `position:relative` drops the width to 101px.

If you need it the same width but still fixed, you can define an invisible wrapper that's the same percentage as the container, and set that to `position: fixed`, having the relative/25% nav inside.

Like so: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v7yy/)

Answer (score -1):

I have made this example and its working well
[image]

`Please Try It`[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bT7Vh/)